# Image that becomes select list on phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to have an image on a webpage that, when tapped, displays the select window (also known as the "wheel") on a phone? Basically, to have an image replace the default display of the drop-down. I would use a regular drop down for desktops, but the image on mobile devices.

I was thinking of having both an image and a drop down on the page and hiding/displaying the correct item based on browser size, and then if the image is clicked on the small size to trigger the proper event of the hidden drop down, but that doesn't actually display the options - it just runs whatever code I had associated with that event on the select tag.

Comment: I had tried background image, but not opacity. The solution below works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible.

All you need to do is create a container for the select, set its opacity to `0` and then give the container a background image.

**Example Code:**

html

```
<div class="image">
    <select>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

css

```
.image { background-image: url(http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/cat/cat-06.jpg); background-size: cover; width: 100px; height: 100px;overflow: hidden; }
select { opacity: 0; height: 250px; font-size: 50px; display: inline-block; margin: 10px; border: 0px; background: transparent; }
```

---

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/zmqBg/6/

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I got sidetracked. This definitely works, thanks so much!